# Bind a new behavior dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="bold knowmore login" id="j-6">
<span>...</span>
</div>
```

and this jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $(".login").on("click", function(){ 
     console.log('login clicked!');
     $(".bold.knowmore").removeClass("login").addClass("displayAdvert");
  });

  $(".displayAdvert").on("click",function(){
    console.log("display was clicked!");
  }); 
});
```

But the output is always:

> > login clicked!

But, for some reason, the HTML is updated but the event always calls the click login.
Someone has an idea how I can resolve it?

Comment: Hi, where do you have the `displayAdvert` at first?

Comment: Just type your question title plus 'jquery' into google and you'll find pages of solutions, one of which being this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @naota, the displayAdvert is attached dynamically when you click the first time the login div and the login is removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses Event Delegation becouse you are adding a class Dynamicly:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".login", function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault();
     console.log('login clicked!');       $(".bold.knowmore").removeClass("login").addClass("displayAdvert");
  });

  $(document).on("click", '.displayAdvert',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    console.log("display was clicked!");
  }); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ynLX/)

Comment: `document` is far too broad

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a **A delegated-events approach**

You're assigning the `.displayAdvert` class dynamically so you need to use .on method with dynamic element delegation:

I suppose you have a static parent in your story, so use it's ID:

```
$(function(){
  $(".login").on("click", function(){ 
     console.log('login clicked!');
     $(".bold.knowmore").removeClass("login").addClass("displayAdvert");
  });

  $("#parent").on("click", ".displayAdvert", function(){
    console.log("display was clicked!");
  }); 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: You can also just use body instead of a parent's ID

Comment: @Shmoopy you can use also `$(document)` but it's too expensive to listen for a bubbling click all the way up the DOM tree also probably triggering unecessary listeners binded to other elements (like in the case of a `body` click listened by a popup... just for example...).

Comment: @Shmoopy, the wider you make the parent element, the less control you have and the worse the performance.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically created elements you can use something like the following:

```
$(document).on("click", ".displayAdvert", function() {
    console.log("display was clicked");
});
```

Comment: `document` is far too broad